# htaccess - redirect DNS entry to sub folder but without sub folder in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My problem is that my domain **example.com** points to the root directory of my server (normal behaviour) but the website is located in the subdirectory **sub**.

With the following **.htaccess** I achieved that my domain is redirected to the subdirectory **sub without changig the URL!**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^/sub /sub%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

The frontpage is displayed correctly and the url is still **example.com** (that's correct). But when I click on a link  to visit a sub page (Example link: example.com/my-company), the page redirects me to **example.com/sub** (so back to the frontpage - I don't want that). After the redirect these links still don't work.

How can I achieve that these links work without the subfolder in the address bar? To summarize:

I redirect my domain **example.com** to a sub folder called **sub** and don't display the folder **sub** in the address bar. I want, that the whole page works without the **sub** folder in the address bar.

In the background we use typo3. Here is the **.htaccess** of the **sub** folder:

```
Options None
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub

RewriteRule ^(typo3|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|typo3conf|typo3temp|uploads|showpic\.php|favicon\.ico)/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3/.*$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php

# to avoid double content
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because RewriteRule will issue a redirect by default. You need to tell it not to perform a redirect. You can do this using the PassThrough floaf [PT]

The following should then work:

```
RewriteRule !^/sub/(.*)$ /sub/$1 [L,NC,PT]
```

Comment: Thank you. Now, it redirects to the page without the sub folder but the site won't be displayed. It stays blank.

Comment: I edited my answer. What happens if you query straight away a page under /sub ?

Comment: I edited my htaccess: The frontpage now loads the wrong css/js files, because the the base-href is pointing to example.com and not to example.com/sub. I changed the baseURL in typo3 but this didn't help.

Comment: When I query the url **example.com/sub/my-company** it works. But still not when I query **example.com/my-company**

Comment: Update: When I query **example.com/my-company** the site redirects me back to **example.com/sub**